# WCF Authentication for a Javascript (Sencha) web app

Tags: javascript, wcf, authentication, rest, extjs

I work on a mobile web app in Javascript(Sencha)/HTML5 with WCF Rest services that needs to use authentication to authenticate users from a custom (MySQL) database in order to customize services responses during the user session.

I search about WCF authentication and founded so many ways that i'am really lost to find the best way to answer my constraints...

Can i really authenticate my user from the WCF web service (with his username and password) and then keep a token or a cookie or whatever that can be used in the following request in order to identify my user and make my response according to that user ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Authentication as you many know can be done in many ways. Username/password, Certificate etc. It really depends upon your requirement.

For e.g. 
If you have a mobile application which is dealing with financial information for a user (such as Bank account) then I would use both user credentials as well as X509Certificates.

If you have an application which is public facing then you can get away with using just certificates (Just client certi).

If you have a B2B application (which I would doubt in this case) then you can use Asymantic certificates (Client and server) in which you will create Both Client and Server certifcates (X509) and give to the client and let the client manually install it on their client devices.

For the simplest senario you can start by try using username and password. So your client app will user username/password to authenticate with a WCF Service at server. 
Follwing my give you a good starting point
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733131.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/CustomUserNamePassAuth2.aspx

Comment: Ok, i already found this kind of pages and i wondered if that kind of solutions will work with a javascript client because every sample i found (and your too) show sample with .net client...

How can i set credentials (username & password) in my javascript (sencha) ?

How the web service will reconnize my user in the following requests ?

Comment: Usually you dont need to do this in javascript at all. This is something that is handled by .NET object model. So you can specify the credentials in web.config (or app.config) which is then used by the mobile application code (not javascript but some sort of compilable code for e.g. C# or VB). Your javascript will use handler to make request to this webservice it would not have expousre to the plumbing of the WCF.

Comment: Sorry but i really don't understand how that will work. Do you mean i need to validate my user first using a ASP.net form ? 

But after that my request to the WS will be send by my sencha proxy. So how , when i will receive a request in my WS, i will know which user has been authenticated in order to personalize my response ?